# Define an interface of IEnumerable<otherInterface>

Tags: c#, generics, interface, ienumerable

```
public interface IValue
{
  int id {get; set;}
  float val {get; set;}
}

public class Value:IValue
{
  public int id {get; set;}
  public float val {get; set;}
}

public interface IIvalueIEnum<T>
    where T:IValue
{
  IEnumerable<T> list {get; set;}
}

public class Collection:IIvalueIEnum<Value>
{
  public List<Value> list {get; set;}
}
```

How to make this? I'm getting "Collection cannot implement IIvalueIEnum because it does not have the matching return type of IEnumerable

Comment: The error message is clear. The property should have the same signature as the one specified in the interface. This means that `List<Value> list` can't be considered an implementation of `IEnumerable<Value> list`

Comment: change the type of `Collection.list` to `IEnumerable<Value>` like the interface demands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is clear. The property should have the same signature as the one specified in the interface. This means that `List<Value> list` can't be considered an implementation of `IEnumerable<Value> list`.

This is actually the logical thing to do. The interface says that `list` can contain any collection, including arrays, lists, queues, anything that implements `IEnumerable<T>`. This should compile:

```
IIvalueIEnum<Value> someEnum=...;
someEnum.list = new []{new Value()};
```

The property though accepts only `List<Value>` items which means it can't accept the values specified by the interface property.

The class should change to:

```
public class Collection:IIvalueIEnum<Value>
{
    public IEnumerable<Value> list {get; set;}
}
```

I suspect that property is only needed for reading an existing collection though, not *assigning* a new `IEnumerable<T>`. That property should probably be read only and point to the actual collection:

```
public interface IIvalueIEnum<T>
where T:IValue
{
    IEnumerable<T> list {get;}
}

public class Collection:IIvalueIEnum<Value>
{
    public IEnumerable<Value> list =>ActualList;
    public List<Value> ActualList{get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to the interface your `list` property needs to return `IEnumarable<T>`, but in the implementation it returns `List<Value>`, which is not the same!

You know, you do not need any `IIvalueIEnum` at all... you can just use `IEnumerable<IValue>`. Or `ICollection<IValue>` if you want to be able to add values to the collection.

Comment: That's not fully true. You cannot use `ICollection<IValue>`, because this is not co-variant. You could not return a `List<Value>` for a `ICollection<IValue>`.